# UIImage from bytes held in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, uiimage, nsdata

I am trying to create a UIImage from a byte array that is actually held within a NSString.

Can someone please tell me how I can do that?

Here is what I was thinking of doing:

```
NSString *sourceString = @"mYActualBytesAREinHERe=";
//get the bytes
const char *bytesArray = [sourceString cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//build the NSData object
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytesArray length:[sourceString length]];
//create actual image
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

The problem is **image** is always 0x0 (nil).

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To convert an image to string you need a method to convert `NSData` to a base64Encoded string and back (lots of examples [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour)). The easiest ones to use are categories on `NSData` so you can do something like this:

```
UIImage* pic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
NSData* pictureData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pic);
NSString* pictureDataString = [pictureData base64Encoding];
```

To go the other way you need a reverse converter:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData 
            dataFromBase64EncodedString: pictureDataString]];
```

Comment: Thanks. The second part of your answer is just what I was after.

Comment: base64Encoding is no longer available method for NSData

Answer (score 0):

`[UIImage imageWithData:data];` will return nil if it doesn't understand the data being passed to it.  I would double check your encoding, etc.  It's odd that a binary string would hold pure image data without some kind of encoding (base64, etc.).  String encodings and binary encodings aren't compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your image data has some null characters in there (0x00) and as you know that is the terminator for the string, so when you ask for the C string, you probably get way-way too little data.

Try something like
- (NSData *)dataUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
to generate your NSData.

If that doesn't work you need to evaluate whether the setting the data into an NSString (with embedded null chars) isn't causing a loss of data too.

Like one of the other respondents, perhaps base-64 encoding your data would be a good idea (if using a string to transport the img data is a requirement)

Good luck.