# How do I convert an LDAP "jpegPhoto" to NSString to UIImageView

Tags: ios, nsstring, uiimage, ldap, openldap

I am trying to pull an LDAP "jpegPhoto" attribute from an openLDAP server using a iOS openLDAP framework. The framework pulls the data as a dictionary of NSStrings.

I need to convert the NSString of "jpegPhoto" (which also appears to be base64 encoded) to UIImage, with the end result being that I display the jpegPhoto as the user's image when they login.

More Info:

```
-(NSDictionary *)doQuery:(NSString *)query:(NSArray *)attrsToReturn {
    ...
    while(attribute){
        if ((vals = ldap_get_values_len(ld, entry, attribute))){
            for(int i = 0; vals[i]; i++){
                //Uncomment if you want to see all the values.
                //NSLog(@"%s: %s", attribute, vals[i]->bv_val);
                if ([resultSet objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",attribute]] == nil){
                    [resultSet setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",vals[i]->bv_val]] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",attribute]];
                }else{
                    NSMutableArray *array = [[resultSet objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",attribute]] mutableCopy];
                    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",vals[i]->bv_val]];
                    [resultSet setObject:array forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",attribute]];
                }
            }
            ldap_value_free_len(vals);
        };
        ldap_memfree(attribute);
        attribute = ldap_next_attribute(ld, entry, ber);
    };
    ...
}

-(UIIMage *)getPhoto{
    NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(uid=%@)",self.bindUsername];
    NSArray *attrsToReturn = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"cn",@"jpegPhoto", nil];
    NSDictionary *rs = [self doQuery:query:attrsToReturn];
    NSString *photoString = [[rs objectForKey:@"jpegPhoto"] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"The photoString is: %i %@",[photoString length],@"characters long"); //returns 4
    NSData *photoData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:photoString];
    UIImage *userPhoto = [UIImage imageWithData:photoData];
    return userPhoto;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.studentNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi %@!",[self.ldap getFullName]];
    self.studentPhotoImage.image = [self.ldap getPhoto];
    [self checkForProctor];
}
```

Comment: Your question is based on a misconception. An LDAP jpegPhoto, and some other attributes, are returned as byte arrays, not strings.

Comment: My co-worker and I just found that. If I'm allowed to I'll post the generalized code for this in a  little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
NSData *dataObj = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:beforeStringImage];
UIImage *beforeImage = [UIImage imageWithData:dataObj];
```

There are many similar questions in Stackoverflow..  Please refer the following links

[UIImage to base64 String Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889478/uiimage-to-base64-string-encoding)

[UIImage from bytes held in NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101002/uiimage-from-bytes-held-in-nsstring)

Comment: Thank you for the information, I've now coded that in, but I'm finding a larger issue. Prior to converting it from the base64 NSString to NSData, the NSString's length says it is only 4 characters.

I'll edit my post with more information.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I solved the issue with the help of our other programmer.

I was pulling the size of the variable that stored the data originally. When I was supposed to use another OpenLDAP method to get the size of the jpegPhoto.

I need to check with my bosses if I can post the code or if its under confidentiality. I think it's a great thing for everyone to have.

Comment: Since your comment did answer the original question I'm going to mark it as correct.

Comment: Sorry Phillip I missed your update..  Glad you solved your problem.. Have a great day..

Answer (score 0):

(Since there has been no working code posted for getting the image data from LDAP, I wanted to add this answer for the benefit of future visitors.)

The missing piece was reading the binary data into an `NSData` object rather than an `NSString` when you have binary data that might contain NULL (zero) values within it, such as images or GUIDs.

`value = [NSData dataWithBytes:vals[0]->bv_val length:vals[0]->bv_len];`

```
+ (NSArray *)searchWithBaseDN:(const char *)baseDN andFilter:(const char *)filter andScope:(int)scope {
    ...
    while(entry)
    {
        // create a dictionary to hold attributes
        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        attribute = ldap_first_attribute(ld, entry, &ber);
        while(attribute)
        {
            if ((vals = ldap_get_values_len(ld, entry, attribute)))
            {
                if (ldap_count_values_len(vals) > 1) {
                    NSMutableArray *values = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                    for(int i = 0; vals[i]; i++) {
                        [values addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:vals[i]->bv_val]];
                    }
                    [dictionary setObject:values forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:attribute]];
                } else {
                    NSObject *value = nil;
                    if (strcmp(attribute, "thumbnailPhoto") == 0 || strcmp(attribute, "objectGUID") == 0) {
                        value = [NSData dataWithBytes:vals[0]->bv_val length:vals[0]->bv_len];
                    } else {
                        value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", vals[0]->bv_val];
                    }
                    [dictionary setObject:value forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:attribute]];
                }


                ldap_value_free_len(vals);
            };
            ldap_memfree(attribute);
            attribute = ldap_next_attribute(ld, entry, ber);
        };
...
}
```